# Postgresql Copy Syntax error

Tags: postgresql

While running copy command on Postgresql I am getting SQL syntax error. Please find below command.

```
COPY analyte (id, name, normal_max, normal_min, unit_of_measure, version, category, data_type) FROM stdin;
16  Cholesterol - HDL (Good)    \N  40  mg/dl   0   3   9
\.
```

**Error**

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "16"
LINE 2: 16 Cholesterol - HDL (Good) \N 40 mg/dl 0 3 9
        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "16"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 109
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script format - a `COPY FROM stdin` statement followed by a stream of data - is designed to be executed by [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html). Most other tools (e.g. pgAdmin) won't know what to do with it.

I'm guessing this script came from `pg_dump`. If you want something which you can run without `psql`, you can use `pg_dump --column-inserts` to dump the table as a series of `INSERT` statements instead of a `COPY`.

Comment: Thanks Nick, got you on Pgadmin it is not working while on sql shell able to add data, Thanks a lot :)